# How do I integrate JBOSS 7 with legacy messaging bus?

Tags: jboss, message-queue

I have a legacy message bus which acts as a broker between other systems (uses POSIX sockets) and is written in C/C++. We have a java client library which creates a persistent connection with this bus.

How can I go about integrating JBOSS 7 AS with the legacy message bus without creating a un-managed thread (using the client library for persistent connection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct and portable way of doing this would be to write a JCA resource adapter (RAR) which uses the client library. The resource adapter has access to the JCA work manager for running tasks in another thread, can register connection factories, and inflow messages to be handled by MDBs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glodb.html and http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/ironjacamar/create-your-first-jca-connector-tutorial may be useful to read.